# Issues switching from jQuery 1.4.4 to 1.6.1

Tags: jquery, version

Should there be any major issues to switch from jQuery 1.4.4 to jQuery 1.6.1?

I just noticed that all of the sites on our system were using 1.4.4.

So should i switch them all over to the newest one (1.6.1) or keep them as is, and if i do switch, what issues may I face?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your safest bet is to go the [jQuery Blog](http://blog.jquery.com/) and go though the change logs from 1.4.4 to 1.6.1. Change logs call out feature changes that would require you to change your code.

Here's a sample:

http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/

Answer (score 4):

You might have issues with `attr`. Prior to jQuery 1.6 `attr("checked")` returned a boolean, now on 1.6+ it returns the attribute value. To get the boolean value you have to use `.prop (added on 1.6)`.

On [**jQuery's blog about 1.6.1 release**](http://blog.jquery.it/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/) you will find information to **upgrade from 1.5.2 to 1.6.1**. This post also tells you a lot of details about `.prop` and `.attr`. You will also find the full change log.

Both [1.5.1 release post](http://blog.jquery.it/2011/02/24/jquery-151-released/) and [1.5.2 release post](http://blog.jquery.it/2011/03/31/jquery-152-released/) doesn't present any information on upgrading, which might mean that there is no big changes to be done, but you have the complete list of changes for these versions that you might want to check guarantee.

See

- [jQuery 1.6.1 release notes](http://blog.jquery.it/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/)
- [jQuery 1.5.2 release notes](http://blog.jquery.it/2011/02/24/jquery-151-released/)
- [jQuery 1.5.1 release notes](http://blog.jquery.it/2011/03/31/jquery-152-released/)
- [javascript - .prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/340760)
- [jQuery .prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

> **Description**: Get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Comment: might want to add this as well to your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr   but this should have been resolved in 1.6.1, no?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you use.  I personally have had no issues when upgrading since 1.3.  Best bet would be to look over the release notes, and see if anything you've used was impacted.

Either way if you decide to try it, test, test, test.

**EDIT**

One thing I forgot.  I did have issues with $.ajax switching to using jsonp for json datatypes.  But I think that got fixed in a later version.

Comment: true, but this is a jump, completely skipping the 1.5 releases

Comment: I understand, I'm saying look at ALL of the release notes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've seen this page http://www.davidtong.me/upgrading-jquery-from-1-4-x-to-1-6-1/ that seems to outline the main issues:

- prop() and attr()
- Ajax and parseJSON
- getAttribute on Flash objects
- Plugins